# JavaScript form validation maxVALUE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Where `minvalue` is now I would actually like to have a `maxvalue` of 12. What is the code for max value instead of min value? Thanks!

This uses jQuery and jquery.validate:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').validate({
        rules: {
            username: {required:true, minlength:12},
            items: {required:true, range:[1,100]},
        }
```

**EDIT**: I realize I actually need max value, not max length, So what is the jQuery for max value?

Comment: this code: a) uses jQuery, b) uses some kind of plugin for validation. Tag this properly please

Comment: nevermind...found the code i needed elsewhere. For anyone reading this, its just {required:true, max:12}

Answer (score 2):

To make an element require a given maximum, use [`max`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/max#value):

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      max: 23
    }
  }
});
```